# Writing a user mode filesystem for windows?

Tags: c#, filesystems

Is it possible to write a filesystem for Windows in pure usermode, or more specifically purely in managed code? I am thinking of something very similar to GMAILFS. Excluding what it is doing under the covers (GMAIL, Amazon, etc..) the main goal would be to provide a drive letter and support all of the basic file operations, and possibly even adding my own structures for storing metadata, etc..

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651171/usermode-file-system

Comment: not a dupe, I am not looking for a library to do this for me, I am looking to do it myself.

Comment: although I might end up having to use that ;)

Comment: By the way although I hardly care about whether it is going to be user mode or not (I'd even prefer system-mode actually so that the data would be available to system services without need for a user to log-in) I am really curious about writing a file system driver in C# and could find nothing interesting on this subject so far...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult. I'd take a look at some projects which have done some of the hard work for you, e.g. [Dokan](https://dokan-dev.github.io/).

Comment: To the best of my understanding Dokan needs to be installed as a kernel-mode driver (Dokan.sys), and only after this can you implement your own user-mode code (optionally in .Net) layered on top...

Comment: There is no way to use Dokan in a commercial project, it is under LGPL license. I would suggest using WebDAV server library (such as http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/) + built-in Windows/Mac OS X drive mounting functionality. Probably this is the fastest way to achieve the result and your server will be standards-compliant in this case.

Comment: @user424257 LGPL allows use in commercial projects (GPL does too in fact). Dokan has it's own shortcomings, though, such as a huge tail of bugs and lack of support and maintenance.

Answer (score 14):

Windows provides several approaches to building a user-mode file system for different purposes, depending on your storage location and features that you need to support. Two of them, Projected File System API and Cloud Files API were recently provided as part of the Windows 10 updates.

### Windows Projected File System API

[Projected File System API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/projfs/projected-file-system) is designed to represent some hierarchical data, such as for example Windows Registry, in the form of a file system.
Unlike Cloud Files (see below) it does not provide any information about file status and hides the fact that this is not the “real” file system. [Example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/ProjectedFileSystem).

### Windows Cloud Sync Engine API

[Cloud Sync Engine API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cfapi/build-a-cloud-file-sync-engine) (Cloud Files API, Cloud Filter API) is used in OneDrive on Windows 10 under the hood. It provides folder content loading during the first request, on-demand files content loading in several different modes, and offline files support. It integrates directly into Windows File Manager and Windows Notification Center and provides file status (offline, in-sync, conflict, pinned) and file content transfer progress.
The Cloud Files API runs under regular user permissions and does not require admin privileges for file system mounting or any API calls. [Example](https://github.com/ITHit/UserFileSystemSamples/tree/master/Windows/VirtualFileSystem).

### Windows Shell Namespace Extensions API

While [Shell Namespace Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/namespace-intro) is not a real file system, in many cases you will use it to extend the functionality of the Projected File System and Cloud Files API. For example, you will it to add custom commands to context menus in Windows File Manager as well as you can create nodes that look and behave like a real file system (again, applications would not be able to read or write to such nodes, this is just a user interface).
Cloud Files API is using a namespace extension to show your sync root at the top level in Windows File Manager.

Comment: With a Shell Namespace Extension, you can perfectly read/write items using 3rd party applications. Also, Cloud Files API is not using a namespace extension. Support (icons, texts, menus, etc.) is built in the Shell directly, the Quick Access link is just registry voodoo: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/integrate-cloud-storage

Comment: Here is the example for Windows Cloud Sync Engine API: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/CloudMirror rather than the linked example that uses the ITHit library

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's possible and has been [successfully done for the ext2 filesystem](http://www.fs-driver.org/).

Note that you will need to write your own driver which will require Microsoft signing to be run on some OSes.

Comment: how is this pure usermode? It's a kernel driver, isn't it??

Comment: Corection - you don't need Microsoft signing for the driver to be loaded. The driver must be signed and countersignature must be included, but it's a different matter. Microsoft signing (WHQL certification, to be correct) is a different story.

Answer (score -1):

Sure, you can abstract the regular file operations and have them running in the cloud (see Google Apps, Amazon S3, Microsoft Azure etc.). But if you'd like to talk to local devices - including the local HD - you'll have to use system APIs and those use drivers (system/kernel mode).

As long as all you want is a storage service -no problem. If you want a real OS, you'll need to talk to real hardware and that means drivers.

Comment: Rather than talking to local hardware, I am actually looking from the other end of it .. how to make my abstracted file system appear as a drive in Windows.