# Emulate NTFS/FAT Partition with Java application

Tags: java, windows, filesystems

Is it possible to emulate an in-memory partition for Windows 7+ from a Java application?

I want to create a git based file system organized by tags, that can be mounted into Windows as a partition (and is therefore mapped into a hierchical folder structure).

Are there any APIs / libraries for building such tasks?

Answer (score 2):

you would have to create some usermode filesystem, which is operating system specific low level code for which java usually not the best solution. but you can probably use some library via java native interface. maybe something like this works for you: [Writing a user mode filesystem for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412763/writing-a-user-mode-filesystem-for-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a virtual filesystem would be needed. There exists our Callback File System product which includes Java API and which is at version 6 now (and is actively maintained and updated). There also exists Dokan whose development was stopped at version 0.6 4 years ago and has been continued now by other team.

Comment: Sound great but I need this for private use only :/

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Dokan library](https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokany) that give you the ability to create a virtual device with the content that you. As exemple, there is a mirror application in main repository that simply mirror a folder of your system as a filesystem or in the C# repository there is an app that create a filesystem from your registry. You can really create whatever filesystem you want with it.

Dokan is now compatible with

```
Windows 10
Windows 8.1
Windows Server 2012 R2
Windows 8
Windows Server 2012
Windows 7
```

There is different wrapper for dokan [C#](https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokan-dotnet), [Delphi](https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokan-delphi) and the [Java](https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokan-java)  wrapper that need to be updated because compatibility has been break with the last version but I can help you to update it if you are motivated !

Comment: This sounds quite perfect for my intention. Maybe you can explain the compatibility problems to me?

Comment: You can find API changes at the end of the 0.8.0 release: https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokany/releases/tag/v0.8.0

   - Change win32 errors to NTSTATUS.
   - Remove the KeepAlive option that no longer exist.
   - Add Mounted & Unmouted DokanOperation
   - Use new CreateFile -> ZwCreateFile (function has been replaced)

If you have more question about it. Open a ticket in the dokan java repository and I will help you the best as I can !